# Software to build a taxi app easily, without vendor lock-in

Tags: android, software-development, ios, security, mobile

Could you please help me narrow my search for software that can be used to make a taxi app?

The app will provide similar functionalities to the lyft app. It should be maintainable and robust. Must be able to handle large number of users at the same time. It must have security features. And, it must run on Android and iOS.

advertisements and branding from/of the software builder are not okay. Usage fees are okay only and only if I can export the app from the software builder platform and have full and complete copyright as the sole owner to all the source code used in building the app.

I found a web-based app service, I like the services they are offering, but I do not like that the app will be locked if I cancel my subscription with them. I want to be able to own the app whether I subscript to them or not. So, I am wondering if there is an alternative to this service which allows me to own my code and own the ability to publish/lock the app on my own.

For websites, I use Bootstrap Studio. I want something similar for Android/iOS Mobile development, with more features such as:

- Unlimited Bandwidth & Hosting
- Unlimited App Editing
- App Analytics with Google Analytics

Quick Summary:
I want an app building software which lets me build my app with little to no code writing, and I want to completely own all copyright to my app source code and services.

Comment: Try to contact someone in Neverland. If it fails please realize that's a job for a well paid company/software developer. And it will be expensive. Be prepared for 5 digits+ sums. If that's not for you why don't you try other idea ? That one is for grown up people. :/